# SharePoint Online Provider Hosted App Context Token Is NULL On Postback

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, office-365, provider-hosted-app, oauth

I have a provider hosted app in SharePoint Online. The problem I have is sometimes on postback the TokenHelper Class method GetContextTokenFromRequest is returning Context Token as NULL

```
  ContextToken = TokenHelper.GetContextTokenFromRequest(Page.Request);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the issue resolved by using view state for the Context Token property

```
 public string ContextToken
       {
            get
           {
            return ViewState["ContextToken"] != null ? Convert.ToString(ViewState["ContextToken"]) : String.Empty;
        }
        set 
        {
            if (value != null)
            {
                ViewState["ContextToken"] = value;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please let me know to which file you added this code (Provider Hosted App + Client Web Part), is it in the SharePointContext.cs ?